# Is every space homology equivalent to an Eilenberg–MacLane space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

Homology equivalence may be defined as follows (any other ways could be not equivalent to one below): $X \sim Y$ if there exist two map $f : Y \to X$, $g : X \to Y$, such that $(fg)^* = id_{H(X)}$ and $(gf)^* = id_{H(Y)}$ (where homology is taken with integer coefficients).

For every CW-complex $X$, does there exist a group $\pi$ such that the Eilenberg–MacLane space $K(\pi, n)$ is homology equivalent to X?

Comment: Infact the converse question seems more interesting to me, i.e " Is there exists a non- Eilenberg-MacLane space which is homologically equivalent to a Eilenberg-MacLane space".

Comment: More over I can extend my question by imposing the assumption that $X$ is a finite dimensional CW complex. Then what would be an answer (to my question)?

Comment: You should require $X$ to be connected at least.  (If $X$ is disconnected, you have to take $n=0$, in which case $K(\pi,n)$ can't have any higher homology.)

Comment: @Eric do you have any answer corresponding to my question?

Comment: @Anubhav: If $Y$ is a $K(\pi,n)$ for $n\neq 1$ you can take $X=Y\times K(G,1)$ where $G$ is a nontrivial group such that $K(G,1)$ has trivial homology.  I don't know about the case $n=1$ or what you can say if you require $X$ to be finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  For instance, take $X=S^2$ and suppose $f:X\to K(\pi,n)$ is a homology equivalence.  Since $f$ is non-nullhomotopic, $\pi_2(K(\pi,n))\neq 0$, so $n=2$.  But then $X$ and $K(\pi,n)$ are simply connected, so $f$ would have to be a homotopy equivalence.  Since $X$ has higher homotopy groups, this is a contradiction.

More generally, a similar argument works whenever $X$ is simply connected and not an Eilenberg-MacLane space (by the Hurewicz theorem, a homology equivalance $f:X\to K(\pi,n)$ must induce a nontrivial map on the first nontrivial homotopy group of $X$, and it follows that $n>1$ so $f$ must be a homotopy equivalence).

I would note, however, that there is a positive result if you require the homology equivalence only to exist as a map in one direction.  The [Kan-Thurston theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan-Thurston+theorem) says that if $X$ is any path-connected space, then there is a group $\pi$ and a map $f:K(\pi,1)\to X$ that induces isomorphisms on homology.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is really great answer.